# Facebook Page Tab not posting signed_request

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-page, facebook-canvas

I'm in the process of creating a Facebook app that uses a *Page Tab*. However, when I access a page where the app is installed a `signed_request` parameter is not sent to my script. Neither `$_POST` nor `$_REQUEST` are being sent any data (*and using the Facebook PHP SDK `$facebook->getSignedRequest()` also does not work*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be a stupid oversight on my end, I had typed `http://example.com` which redirected to `http://www.example.com` the redirected page didn't have data posted to it.